# Is running git update-index --refresh from PS1 prompt safe?

Tags: git, bash, optimization, command-line, ps1

I've been researching the fastest way to check for changes in a repo to update the PS1 prompt. For reasons not worth elaborating, no access to the __git_ps1() macro, and anyway other posts have suggested various commands, including those used in __git_ps1().

Reason: I'm accessing repos on a remote server over VPN & ssh, with the remote repo tunnelled back through my connection to our in-house git server. I'm guessing (but really not sure if this is true) that this may be the reason that on a fresh connection on a new day, cd'ing into a repo on this remote server can cause `git ls-files -m` to take 3 or 4 seconds to complete, and still take up to 1 second after file caching has helped.

To improve this I found `git diff-index --quiet HEAD` is almost instant, but the next day it starts returning '1' even though there are actually no changes (no output from a very slow run of `git status`). I've found that `git update-index --refresh -q` seems to fix the issue (quickly) and also returns '0' if in fact there are no changes.

From what I've read I *think* it should be safe to run from PS1 prompt, but I understand this is a "lower level" git command and I may not be understanding all the implications. So, to be clear, I've currently got the following to check for changes, which always seems to be quick, but after a day starts outputting '*' in clean repos.

```
if git diff-index --quiet HEAD 2>/dev/null && [[ -z "$(git ls-files --others --exclude-standard --directory --no-empty-directory)" ]]
    then echo -n " "
    else echo -n " *"
fi
```

Can any "git gurus" out there see a problem with changing 1st test to `git update-index --refresh -q`?

Answer (score 1):

It should work, except when use in a [Git LFS (Large File Storage)](https://git-lfs.github.com/) where, as [explained here](https://www.spinics.net/lists/git/msg428075.html), it can trigger racy timestamps.

That is why, with Git 2.36 (Q2 2022), "[`git update-index --refresh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ee52b35e503fda30a269212823cc3dc67c907af7/Documentation/git-update-index.txt#L54)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#Documentation/git-update-index.txt---refresh))</sup> has been taught to deal better with racy timestamps (just like "[`git status`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ee52b35e503fda30a269212823cc3dc67c907af7/Documentation/git-status.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status))</sup> already does).

See [commit 2ede073](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2ede073fd2287eb91af26484c2e7dafc15ecb7b7), [commit 9b71efd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9b71efd01489d6c93436740e4c1b3eadeb0c719b), [commit 0275e4d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0275e4daabed330c4d27cc9a482c2d23d7544aca), [commit ab6245b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ab6245bdeed46e1ff3bd378690066abd2ed0f2ef) (07 Jan 2022) by [Marc Strapetz (`mstrap`)](https://github.com/mstrap).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit ee52b35](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ee52b35e503fda30a269212823cc3dc67c907af7), 05 Feb 2022)</sup>

> ### [`update-index`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2ede073fd2287eb91af26484c2e7dafc15ecb7b7): refresh should rewrite index in case of racy timestamps
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Marc Strapetz</sup>

> '[`git update-index --refresh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/2ede073fd2287eb91af26484c2e7dafc15ecb7b7/Documentation/git-update-index.txt#L54)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#Documentation/git-update-index.txt---refresh))</sup> and '--really-refresh' should force writing of the index file if racy timestamps have been encountered, as '[`git status`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/2ede073fd2287eb91af26484c2e7dafc15ecb7b7/Documentation/git-status.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status))</sup> [already does](https://lore.kernel.org/git/d3dd805c-7c1d-30a9-6574-a7bfcb7fc013@syntevo.com/).
>
> Note that calling '`git update-index --refresh`' still does not guarantee that there will be no more racy timestamps afterwards (the same holds true for '`git status`'): - calling '`git update-index --refresh`' immediately after touching and adding a file may still leave racy timestamps if all three operations occur within the racy-tolerance (usually 1 second unless `USE_NSEC` has been defined) - calling '`git update-index --refresh`' for timestamps which are set into the future will leave them racy
>
> To guarantee that such racy timestamps will be resolved would require to wait until the system clock has passed beyond these timestamps and only then write the index file.
> Especially for future timestamps, this does not seem feasible because of possibly long delays/hangs.